# Opening a file in Mac OS X

Tags: c, file, macos

I am trying to open a text file with C++ in Mac OS X but I always get a Bus error.

I do not care where to put the file. I just need to read it. Am I writing its address wrong? or that Bus Error has another reason?

```
FILE *dic;
dic = fopen("DICT","rb");

dic = fopen("./DICT","rb");

dic = fopen("~/DICT","rb");

dic = fopen("~//DICT","rb");
```

Comment: That's C, not C++. Are you sure you mean to use C++ and not C?

Comment: dic should be a file pointer but here fopen returns Null

Comment: Provided the file exists in the current directory, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Can you post some more context code?

Comment: so, what does perror() say after fopen?

Comment: If `fopen()` returns `NULL` then the file didn't open successfully, which most probably mean it doesn't exist in the current directory.

Comment: This code (File address was different) works on a PC. But I have to run it on a iMAC.

Comment: @Pooya: If `fopen` _returns_ `NULL`, the error occurs _after_ the call. Could it be that you are just dereferencing that `NULL` pointer?

Comment: @Vlad: No, `fopen` returns null on failure.

Comment: @Billy I think Vlad is referring to the error that causes fopen to fail... there are two errors: 1. the file isn't getting opened and 2. it's crashing

Comment: @Billy: s/error/crash/ in my comment

Comment: The error happens in this line:
fseek(dic,0,SEEK_END);
and it is because, fopen returns NULL

Comment: so, what does perror() say after fopen?

Comment: Well, than the behaviour is expected. If `dic` is `NULL`, you must not give it as argument to `fseek`. It happens to work on PC just because in that case the file can be opened, so the `dic` is not `NULL`.

Comment: I want to put the file somewhere (ex. on Desktop) to pass its address correctly to this function. However, as I am a new Max OS user, I am not sure this file address.

Comment: Desktop is /users/<short username>/Desktop/

Comment: You seem to be a new C user, too.

Comment: ... and of course you should check the value returned from `fopen`, even if you spell the file path correctly!

Comment: Yes, I am a new C programmer too. I am not administrator of this machine, could it be some how related?

Comment: @Pooya: Most probably not if you created that file. Hint - right-click on a file in finder, then `Get Info` and under `General:` look at `Where:`.

Comment: `~` is probably not going to be expanded as you expect (since it's generally expanded by the shell).  You would need to use some other method to find the home directory, like `$HOME` or `getwpent` which should exist under BSD/OS X.

Answer (score 3):

With a little bit of clarification I see the problem in your C code (not C++!) is that `fopen()` returns `NULL`. You can check what the problem really is by reporting the detailed error:

```
if( (dic = fopen("DICT", "rb") == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", perror("ERROR:"));
    exit(1);
}
```

If `fopen()` fails to find the file on the user's desktop and you wish your code to work on multiple platforms then you might define a function to get the user's desktop directory for using with `fopen()`. Something like

```
char* user_desktop(char* buf, size_t len)
{
    const char* const DESKTOP_DIR = 
#ifdef PC
    "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Pooya\\Desktop\\"
#elif defined(OSX)
    "/Users/Pooya/Desktop/"
#elif defined(LINUX)
    "/home/users/pooya/Desktop/"
// fail to compile if no OS specified ...
#endif
    return strncpy(buf, DESKTOP_DIR, len);
}
```

You probably want to look into a more robust way of getting the path of the desktop for each operating system. Most operating systems have an API for this, so do your research. There are also more robust ways of splitting behaviour for various platforms, you can look into that or open a different question about that. I just wanted to express my idea, of having a function which will return you the appropriate desktop path no matter on which platform you compile your code.

Comment: Hard-coding paths is no portable solution.

Comment: Yes, I just want to give a clear idea of what I mean. Most operating systems have API for getting this sort of paths, but putting that in code here would distract from my point.

Comment: Something was wrong about the file. I have saved it again and it works right now.

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct! Pay attention to the directory where the executable is located. For sure the directory of the execution is not the same as you are expecting (I suppose, the directory of the `.c` files, right?).

I believe you are executing the app from the IDE. This is commom in Xcode, it mounts the exec`s in another location than that where the project files are located, and this such location that is considered when you execute the program, whether you execute it from the IDE or not!

Simply move the file you want to read to the location of the application and it will work properly.

Comment: the file might not have been in the correct location, but the questioned did not seem to rely on it being in a directory relative to the current one as some of his examples were relative to his home directory. Also, moving files to the application directory is not always practical!