# Is it possible to use fopen to read a file with a relative path in C on OS X?

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to do something like that in my API:

```
char* fileName = "./path/to/file.bmp";
Texture* tex = (Texture *) malloc(sizeof(Texture));
FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
```

But for some reason `file` is coming up null.

Is there a way to get this file descriptor with a relative path?

I see many questions about that, but nothing that can give me a way to perform this on OS X.

Comment: Something of note: OS X is BSD-derived, hence by definition complies to the POSIX standard. Any solution that runs on a POSIX supported OS that will also work on OS X. Succinctly: if it works for mainstream Linux distros (Ubuntu,  etc.), it'll work for you too.

Comment: The path is correct is the relative path from the main.c file.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current directory at the time the code is executed, not relative to the C source code.

Comment: keshlam, you is correct, i tried with a relative path from the project directory and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. My project folder is something like this:

```
project
|_ src
|_ examples
   |_ example1
      |_ main.c
      |_ assets
         |_ file.bmp
```

I was trying to get the file descriptor from the `main.c`. The filePath would be `assets/file.bmp`, but this isn´t true; I can get the file descriptor with the path from project folder, and the relative file path is `examples/example1/assets/file.bmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the return value of fopen. 
i.e

```
FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
if(file==NULL)
{
    printf("File can't opened!!");
    exit(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "can't get the file info" ? All your snippet shows is that you've assigned a filename (which happens to be relative to where your process is running), you've assigned a (Texture *) variable, and acquired a file handle by calling fopen().

All fopen() does is open the file for you. If you want get data from the file, you have to fread() or fscanf() it, eg (assuming that the file contents is binary and that we don't care about whether we read the whole file correctly):

```
(void)fread(tex, sizeof(Texture), 1, file);
```

Two other things: #1 I'd call my filehandle something different, like `fd` or `inputfd` - it helps to reduce the potential for confusion, and #2 use calloc() rather than malloc() - it zeros out the space allocated for you.

What else does your code do?

Comment: Sorry i mean open the file to get the info.

Comment: If you're getting an error from `fopen()`, then you should see what it is and handle it appropriately. There are a number of return codes defined for `fopen()`, and their explanations in the standard library manpage for the function should make it clear what's going on.

You might also find it helpful to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615492/opening-a-file-in-mac-os-x; I've found the Solaris manpages to be very good too: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29034/fopen-3c.html#scrolltoc